# Xamarin Studio Designer error - Custom iOS Control using MvxView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, custom-controls, mvvmcross

I've created a custom iOS control using Xamarin Studio and while it works fine at runtime when I open the xib which has the control dropped onto it the interface builder displayed it with a nasty error (below).

[image: Control rendered in Xamarin Studio designer]

The project uses MvvmCross and the backing class for the xib inherits from MvxView - and herein lies the problem. If I change this to a standard UIView the control is displayed just fine - but I lose the binding capabilities I need.

Now - I'm not expecting the designer to display a nicely rendered interpretation of my control, I know that won't happen.

What I want to know is whether this error is a byproduct of using MvxView and I just need to live with it or whether I've missed something in my implementation - I'm guessing I've not overridden something but can't work out what it is.

**[Edit: 18 Nov 2016]**

Digging through the MvvmCross code on Github I've located the cause of the problem - but I'm no closer to fixing it.

Basically the backing class for my control has the standard constructor (this is the line referenced in the error that I've partially blurred):

```
public ResidentHeaderView(IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{

}
```

Following the stacktrace up from there it turns out that the code is trying to resolve a BindingContext and failing - because I am in designtime here.
If I comment out the constructor and rebuild then the error in the designer disappears - and of course the app will crash when I access a page that contains this control because the contructor is required.

So I know why it's happening (and that it's nothing serious in my code) but I don't know how I can resolve it.

Any further input greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: My VS storyboard designer crashes all the time with similar nasty box especially when I try to do constraints. I feel your pain :-) I gave up and use XCode designer